# How to write a Lua script to insert multiple hashes using list of keys and values

Tags: redis, lua

I need to write a Lua script for inserting 100K records in Redis. The data structure identified in Hash. Sample Redis: `redis.call('hmset', 'key1', 'field1','value1')`

I am using below script but it needs to be called multiple times `redis.call('hmset', KEYS[1], unpack(ARGV))`

I need a Lua script which accepts list of string and list of map, so that I can use a `for` loop and insert all records in one shot.

Any sample script would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to do what you need:

```lua
for _, k in ipairs(KEYS) do
  redis.call('HSET', k, unpack(ARGV))
end
```

Comment: Thank you @Itamar for the answer.
I used below script

`for i=1, #KEYS do
redis.call('hmset', KEYS[i], unpack(ARGV))
i=i+1
end`

This script is taking around 3 secs for inserting 100K keys with 20 field,value pairs each.
But it times out if I run for 1M keys.
Any suggestions to improve the script performance.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're opting to use a Lua script? Why not just send HSETs with a pipeline?

Comment: I am trying to see if Lua scripting can give better performance than pipeline.
Also is there any way I can pass List<Maps> to the ARGV for below script:

for _, k in ipairs(KEYS) do
  redis.call('HSET', k, unpack(ARGV))
end